# How to separate index in pivot table in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pivot-table

I know there are 3 primary parameters in pivot_table. Index, columns and fill_value.

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index='userID',columns='days',fill_value=0)    # Fill 0
```

I can't pivot my dataframe because of the memory problem.

So is it possible to split the `index` to small parts then merge those pivot tables together to solve this problem?

For example, `userID` was in range(0,1000000), I want to cut them to 3 parts:(0,333333),(333333,666666)and (666666,1000000). Then combine these 3 into one pivot table.

Comment: What is days/what does the original dataframe look like? Perhaps there is a better/alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df.query('UserID < @i').pivot_table(index='UserID', 
                   columns='days', fill_value=0) for i in [333333,666666,1000000]])
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `np.array_split`

```
pd.concat([x.pivot_table(index='UserID',\
        columns='days', fill_value=0) for x in np.array_split(df, 3)])
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that in general I don't think you can safely concat pivot_tables (in the sense that the concat of the pivot_table(splits) is the same as pivot_table(df) )